# My http webserver written in c doesn't show the html file

Tags: c, sockets, networking, winsock2

I'm building a web server based on the c sockets after I did all what I have the connection is successfully established but not showing the html on the browser

It's just loading endlessly without showing anything
For more details you can see my git hub
https://github.com/mostafashraf18/webserver/tree/main

The code
`

```
#include "../include/server.h" 
 #include <stdio.h> 
  
 #define BACKLOG 10 
  
  
 int main() { 
  
   WSADATA wsaData; 
  
  if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) { 
  fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n"); 
  exit(1); } 
  if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || 
  HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) { 
  fprintf(stderr,"Versiion 2.2 of Winsock is not available.\n"); 
  WSACleanup(); 
  exit(2); 
   } 
  
    
   FILE *html_data; 
   html_data = fopen("index.html", "r"); 
  
   char response[1024]; 
   fgets(response, 1024, html_data); 
  
   char http_header[2048] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"; 
   strcat(http_header, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"); 
   strcat(http_header, "\r\n"); 
   strcat(http_header, response); 
  
   int server_socket; 
   server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    
  
   struct sockaddr_in server_address; 
   server_address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
   server_address.sin_port = htons(8001); 
   server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    
  
    
    
   bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)); 
  
   listen(server_socket, BACKLOG); 
   int client_socket; 
   while(1){ 
      
     client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL); 
     send(client_socket, http_header, sizeof(http_header), 0); 
     close(client_socket); 
   } 
    
    
    
   return 0; 
    
  
 }
```

I tried Changing the http massages, I expecting to know where is the bug

Comment: The first debugging step would be to check the return values of the `socket`, `bind`, `accept` and `send` functions, in order to determine whether any of these functions is reporting an error. Please [edit] the question to specify the result of this investigation.

Comment: The connection have been established I checked but the problem is that the html not showing alot of people told the problem in "\r\n" but I tried changing it and it's still doesn't work

Comment: You need to add a content length header to the http headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `fgets` will only read a single line of data, so it will only read the following line from your `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This explains why your browser is only showing an empty page.

If you want to read the entire file into `response`, I suggest that you either call `fgets` in a loop or use `fread` instead. If you use `fread`, then you will have to add the terminating null character manually, because `fread` will not write one.

I suggest that you replace the line

```
fgets(response, 1024, html_data);
```

with:

```
size_t chars_read = fread( response, 1, sizeof response - 1, html_data );
response[chars_read] = '\0';
```